# Asp.net JqGrid: Getting grid's EDIT post to go as Application/Json?

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I'm using JqGrid with my WebForms website setup to get data from a [WebMethod()].  That's working, but now I need to get the edit post to send the content back as "Application/json", but I'm having no luck. Watching Fiddler, I see the post go back as "Application/x-www-form-urlencoded" - I thought I found and set all the correct options, but it's still a no-go.

Here's the grid setup:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.edit, {
    ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" },         
});

jQuery("#<%=jqGridName%>").jqGrid({
        editurl: "/web/juicepress-misc-settings.aspx/saveJpUserException",
        ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json" },
        ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json" },
        prmNames: { 
            search: "isSearch", 
            nd: null, 
            rows: "numRows", 
            page: "page", 
            sort: "sortField", 
            order: "sortOrder"
        },
        // Default values for search to make sure that the ajax call doesn't fail
        postData: { searchString: '', searchField: '', searchOper: '' },
        datatype: function(postdata) {                
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Web/juicepress-misc-settings.aspx/getJpUserExceptions',  
                type: "POST",  
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                data: JSON.stringify(postdata),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data, st) {                        
                    if (st == "success") {
                        var grid = $("#<%=jqGridName%>")[0];
                        var gridData = data.d;                                                  
                        grid.addJSONData(gridData);
                    }
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Error with AJAX callback");
                }
            });
        },
        height: <%=height %>,
        width: <%=width %>,
        jsonReader: {                  
            id: "<%= keyDataField %>", //index of the column with the PK in it                 
            repeatitems: false
        },
        colNames: [ <%= getColumnHeaders() %> ],
        colModel: [ <%= getColumns() %> ],
        multiselect: false,
        gridview: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        caption: "<%= gridTitle %>",
        gridComplete: function(){                    
            var ids = jQuery("#<%=jqGridName%>").jqGrid('getDataIDs');                    
            for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){
                var cl = ids[i];                        
                be = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='E' onclick=\"jQuery('#<%=jqGridName%>').editRow('"+cl+"');\"  />"; 
                se = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='S' onclick=\"jQuery('#<%=jqGridName%>').saveRow('"+cl+"');\"  />";                    
                jQuery("#<%=jqGridName%>").jqGrid('setRowData',cl,{act:be+se});
            }   
        }
    });
```

My service is a [WebMethod] decorated method in the page:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static void saveJpUserException(string name, string description, string oper, int id) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently editing in-line does not use "ajaxEditOptions", instead it uses "ajaxRowOptions" (go figure)...

So the fix it this:

```
ajaxRowOptions: { contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json" }
```